# How to tell if TFS vNext build failed via variable?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am trying to perform different actions (such as copying to a different directory on publish) if a build failed or not.  I am unable to find any documentation about any variables that let me know if it failed or not.  Can anyone let me know how to tell if the build failed or not?

Comment: Are you using Release Management to publish files? Or you want to know the pass/fail status for build step in the build definition and then determine where to publish files in the next step?

Comment: We have some QA people without MSDN accounts.  Without access to TFS, they cannot determine if the build they are seeing published on the network failed or not.  I would like to append success or failure to the network path.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a PowerShell script to call [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/builds#GetbuilddetailsTimeline) to get the build information (You need to enable the alternative credential):

```
[String]$buildID = "$env:BUILD_BUILDID"
[String]$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
[String]$projecturi = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"

$username="alternativeusername"
$password="alternativepassword"

$basicAuth= ("{0}:{1}"-f $username,$password)
$basicAuth=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers= @{Authorization=("Basic {0}"-f $basicAuth)}

$url= $projecturi + $project + "/_apis/build/builds/" + $buildID + "/timeline?api-version=2.0"
Write-Host $url

$responseBuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Get | select records
```

And then you can check the result in the information to see if there is any failed steps and then perform the actions you want:

```
foreach ($record in $responseBuild.records)
{
    $result = $record.result
    ##xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
```